# Proving $\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} dz = 0$, where $f=u+iv$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}-\{0\}$ and $D$ is the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

*This is a very elementary question. Still I can't quite understand what is going on here, so a detailed explanation is appreciated.

> Now suppose we have $f: C-\{0\} \to C$ be an analytic function. Write f = u + iv, and we wish to prove
> $$\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} dz = 0$$ where $D$ denote the unit circle.

I wonder what is the standard approach for this. My next step is

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} dz 
&= \int_{\partial D} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) d(x+iy) \\[6pt]
&= \int_{\partial D} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) dx + i\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)dy
\end{align}$$

Then we write the equation as
$$\int_{\partial D} \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right) dx + i(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})dy) = \int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial v}{\partial \bar z} dz$$

But then I am stuck because $v$ is not analytic (just harmonic) from $f$ analytic, so I can't conclude the integral goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with $\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz=0$, which implies
$\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} dz=-i \int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} dz$.

Now: $\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x v-i\partial_y v)$.
Using Cauchy-Riemann relations: $\partial_x v=-\partial_y u$ and $\partial_y v=\partial_x u$
hence: $-i\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}=\frac{-i}{2}(-\partial_y u-i\partial_x u)=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} $
plugging this in the equality between integrals give: $\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} dz=0$.

Comment: Should it be $\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} dz = 0$ ?

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic and therefore so is $\partial_z f$. Therefore its integral over a loop is null. By definition, holomorphic means $\partial_{\bar z} f=0$

Comment: Can you explain more on how we arrive at $\int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$? I am a bit confused now...

Comment: In your lecture notes you certainly have this result (often called Cauchy integral theorem): Let $\Omega$ be an open and simply connected set and $f$ holomorphich in $\Omega$, then for any loop $\gamma \subset \Omega$: $\int_{\gamma} f=0$

Comment: How do we know $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} $ holomorphic?

Comment: I think it is more of a notation problem... To me, I understand $f'(z) $ is definitely holomorphic, but I don't know whether $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} $ = f'(z) or not, thanks for your detailed explanation

Comment: $df=\partial_z f dz+\partial_{\bar z} f d{\bar z}=\partial_z f dz$ for holomorphic $f$.